# What is the point of the StatusBarItem class in WPF?

Tags: wpf, statusbar, statusbaritem

How is the [`StatusBarItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.statusbaritem.aspx) class supposed to be used? Is every element in a `StatusBar`'s content supposed to be wrapped with it?

I don't really understand how `StatusBarItem` affects the `StatusBar` layout. It seems like I can use `HorizontalAlignment` on a `StatusBarItem`, but not when I put the element in the `StatusBar` directly:

```
<StatusBar>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="Not right" />
    <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Center" />
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

Also if you wrap a `Separator` in a `StatusBarItem` the `Separator` changes to horizontal. `Separator`s default to vertical when put in the `StatusBar` directly without a `StatusBarItem` wrapper.

Comment: i had a similar problem using `Separator` with `ToolBar` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274370/

Comment: Not an answer, but its an ItemsControl, which means you can bind it to a collection of objects and use DataTemplates to determine how those items are displayed in the status bar.  Probably it offers some better behavior in a StatusBar than a standard ItemsControl.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A `StatusBar` is an `ItemsControl`. All `ItemsControl`s have a container class. For `ListBox`es, it's `ListBoxItem`. For `StatusBar`, it's `StatusBarItem`. If you don't explicitly wrap your item in a `StatusBarItem`, it will be implicitly wrapped in one for you.

If you need to set properties of an `ItemsControl`'s containers, you can use the `ItemContainerStyle` property:

```
<StatusBar>
    <TextBlock>One</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Two</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Three</TextBlock>
    <StatusBar.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="StatusBarItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        </Style>
    </StatusBar.ItemContainerStyle>
</StatusBar>
```

Finally, note that the `StatusBar` uses a `DockPanel` by default to lay out its children. This can be frustrating when you're doing intricate layouts. See my blog post [here](https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/the-perfect-wpf-statusbar) on how to swap it out for a `Grid`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the blog post! The following worked for me `<StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>`